# What type of isomers are cis-but-2-ene and 2-methylpropene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, isomers, cis-trans-isomerism

One of my homework problems is asking whether *cis*-but-2-ene and methylpropene are cis-trans isomers or constitutional isomers. But I'm not sure about whether cis-trans isomers include those which the two functional groups exist on the same carbon in the double bond. So does it?

I've searched on Google and looked in my textbook, but they doesn't seem to have anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(2​*Z*)-But-2-ene and 2-methylprop-1-ene are constitutional isomers as they have different connectivities, i.e. the sequence in which the atoms are bonded to each other is not the same. For example, the carbons highlighted here are different: in (2​*Z*)-but-2-ene it is only bonded to *two* other carbons (through a single bond and a double bond), but in 2-methylprop-1-ene it is bonded to *three* other carbons:

[image: Constitutional isomers]

*Cis*/*trans* isomers are a subset of [stereoisomers, which need to have the same *constitution*, or molecular connectivity](https://doi.org/10.1351/goldbook.S05984). The two isomers of but-2-ene satisfy this:

[image: Configurational isomers]

Note how both highlighted carbons are now bonded to the same partners, but with a different spatial arrangement.